# Accessing product category attributes in Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation

Tags: ce-1.8.1.0, menu, category-tree

I am completely new to Magento and have just now installed Magento Community Edition 1.8.1.0.  I have created a few product categories from the admin console.  I would like to customize the top menu based on some attributes of individual product categories.  I have figured out that the changes I need to make will be in a class that overrides `Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation`.

The method `_renderCategoryMenuItemHtml` in this class is invoked with a category.  Specifically, I need `Is Anchor`, `Description` and `Page Title` attributes of the category in this method besides the usual ID, name and URL.  I can see that the category passed to this method is an instance of `Varien_Data_Tree_Node` but this instance does not contain the three attributes I need.

I know that I can use the category ID available inside this method to run queries on the database to get the information I need, but I do not want to do this due to performance reasons.  I am assuming that there is some code that is fetching category information from the database and is setting that information in `Varien_Data_Tree_Node` instances.  I would like to enhance that code to include the additional attributes I need.  However, I have been unable to find that code even after spending 2 days on this.

Can someone point me to the code where I can set the additional attributes in the `Varien_Data_Tree_Node` instance?  Any alternate way of getting category attributes in the Navigation Block would also be helpful, as long as they do not affect performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loading the categories for use in the navigation are done via the function `getStoreCategories` in the class `Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation`:

```
/**
 * Get catagories of current store
 *
 * @return Varien_Data_Tree_Node_Collection
 */
public function getStoreCategories()
{
    $helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category');
    return $helper->getStoreCategories();
}
```

Here you can see the call to the helper's `getStoreCategories` function. On looking closer into this function you can provide the following attributes.

```
$sorted=false, $asCollection=false, $toLoad=true
```

If you update the call to getStoreCategories add set the second attribute to true then you will get a collection of categories rather than a Varien_Data_Tree_Node_Collection, this collection should contain the fields that you need.

Comment: I think I had tried this but was still getting `Varien_Data_Tree_Node` instances.  Will try again and report on how it goes.